# Java: Creating an Instance of a Subclass from the Superclass in a static method

Tags: java, inheritance, static-methods

I am trying to create a new Instance of a subclass from my Super Class. This is my super class

```
public abstract class Worker {

    String world;

    protected abstract void onLoad(Scanner read);

    public static Worker load(Scanner read) {
        // I want to create the instance of my sub class here and call it w
        w.onLoad(read);
        return w;
    } 

    public void setWorld(String world) {
        this.world = world;
    }

}
```

And this is my subclass

```
public class Factory extends Worker {

    @Override
    protected onLoad(Scanner read) {
        setWorld(read.readline());
    }

}
```

And this is what I want to do with those classes.

```
public class MainClass{

    public List<Factory> loadFactories() {
        List<Factory> facts = new ArrayList<Factory>();
        Scanner read = new Scanner(new FileInputStream("factory.txt"));

        while(read.hasNextLine()) {
            Factory f = (Factory)Factory.load(read);
            facts.add(f);
        }

        read.close();
        return facts;
    }

}
```

Is there any way I can do this without starting over? Thanks for any help.

Comment: You haven't made `Worker` a subclass yet.

Comment: A good start if you want Factory to be a subclass of Worker is to write: `class Factory extends Worker`.

Comment: What's supposed to be a subclass of what here?

Comment: Sorry I wrote this really fast.

Comment: @user1816686 It is difficult to understand what you are trying to achieve. `Factory.load(read)` actually calls `Worker.load(read)` which returns a `NoInputWorker` which you assign to a `Factory`... Some pieces of the puzzle are still missing...

Comment: Okay I hopfully now have everything fixed.

Comment: Your static method Worker.load won't know anything about the subclass Factory- and you can't override static methods and get the behaviour you want. Why are you using a static method? Why not just instantiate Factory in MainClass?

Comment: Two questions. Firstly, how should the decision be made as to whether a `Factory` or a `Pipeline` is needed? Does `MainClass` specify it? Should the factory method decide based on the input? Secondly, you say in a comment that you "want to tell if it is a Pipeline or a Factory" - where do you want to tell, and why?

Comment: Basicly I'm gonna combine all my Workers classes saved in one file so I will have a loadWorkers() so when it read the file one like will be "Factory" or "Pipeline" and thats how I will know which one is which. Is it possible to create an instance of a class with the Class object?

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you want?

```
public static Worker load(Scanner read) {
    Factory w=new Factory();
    w.onLoad(read);
    return w;
}
```

---

Edit:

```
public class MainClass {

    public List<Factory> loadFactories() throws FileNotFoundException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
        final List<Factory> facts = new ArrayList<Factory>();
        final Scanner read = new Scanner(new FileInputStream("factory.txt"));

        while (read.hasNextLine()) {
            final Factory f = Worker.load(read, Factory.class);
            facts.add(f);
            final Pipeline p = Worker.load(read, Pipeline.class);
        }

        read.close();
        return facts;
    }

    static public class Factory extends Worker {

        @Override
        protected void onLoad(final Scanner read) {

        }

    }

    static public class Pipeline extends Worker {

        @Override
        protected void onLoad(final Scanner read) {

        }

    }

    static public abstract class Worker {

        String world;

        protected abstract void onLoad(Scanner read);

        public static <T extends Worker> T load(final Scanner read, final Class<T> t) throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
            final T w = t.newInstance();
            w.onLoad(read);
            return w;
        }

        public void setWorld(final String world) {
            this.world = world;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure why this has been down voted- it's the only answer if you take the question at face value!

Comment: To me it look like a perfect example of Factory design pattern! I cannot possibly interpret it in another way. Of course the main method should be Worker f = Worker.load(read);

Comment: Yes but not exactly. Lets say I have another Worker class called Pipeline and I want to tell if it is a Pipeline or a Factory (without an enum).

Comment: like if (w instanceof Pipeline)... ?

Comment: Factory f = (Factory)Worker.load(read); could lead to problems - if you add the Pipeline class. A typical use is to return Worker, without letting the user know what class you are ACTUALLY passing back (allowing you to change it later)

Comment: But how could I get an instance of Pipeline or Factory with using the super class and not knowing which subclass the static method is using.

Comment: Have you thought about using generics? You will have to pass the name of your subclass to the load function

Comment: I just did and I also thought of just using the class itsself. How would you use generics?